# Trying to extend my partition with AWS, but permission denied

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, partition, permission-denied

Lately, I got a problem with my AWS server on EC2 with Linux. For some reason, my web app stopped to load, and after spending some time knowing why, it appears that the available space is full (I have no idea why, it's not like if anyone would upload anything...)
I tried several things I found on google, but sadly, none of them would work since there is no space left on the device. The only solution left was to increase the volume and the partition. The former is done, but I can do the later because it appears that the permission is denied. I followed the tutorial to proper increase the partition in AWS's website itself, but it doesn't work. Here is the problem I'm getting:

```
ubuntu@***:~$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0          7:0    0  24.8M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6563
loop1          7:1    0  24.4M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6312
loop2          7:2    0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1879
loop3          7:3    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2751
loop4          7:4    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322
loop5          7:5    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1891
loop6          7:6    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19361
loop7          7:7    0  53.2M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19122
loop8          7:8    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2745
nvme0n1      259:0    0    25G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0  11.9G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p14 259:2    0     4M  0 part
└─nvme0n1p15 259:3    0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
ubuntu@***:~$ df -hT
Filesystem      Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       ext4    12G   12G     0 100% /
tmpfs           tmpfs  471M     0  471M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           tmpfs  189M   20M  169M  11% /run
tmpfs           tmpfs  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p15 vfat   105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs           tmpfs   95M  4.0K   95M   1% /run/user/1000
ubuntu@***:~$ growpart /dev/nvme0n1p1 1
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/growpart.10717’: No space left on device
FAILED: failed to make temp dir
ubuntu@***:~$ resize2fs /dev/root 1
resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
open: Permission denied while opening /dev/root
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try with `sudo`.

Comment: Ack, I feel a bit dumb... I'm usually not a big user of Linux, I'm learning ^^" Permission isn't denied anymore, but I get another problem... It looks like it doesn't want to increase the volume, and I don't know why. The allowed volume is supposed to be  up to 25G, but it doesn't want to increase.
I either get "The filesystem is already 3117307 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!" or "The containing partition (or device) is only 3117307 (4k) blocks. You requested a new size of 3932160 blocks." if I try to specify a size.

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to resize a partition, but you should actually go to the Amazon EC2 console, select the Amazon EBS volume and use **Modify** to change the size of the virtual disk. Then, reboot your EC2 instance and a startup script will automatically extend the volume to the space available on the EBS volume.

Comment: That's the thing, I already modified the volume of EC2's storage. I stopped and restarted the EC2 a few times, but the problem is still there.

Comment: *sighs* Well, actually, that didn't come in mind, but it seems like the storage was REALLY full to the point it couldn't do anything anymore... I removed a random picture from a data folder and tried growpart again, and it worked fine this time. (so sudo resize2fs worked as well).
Well, still thank you for trying to help.

Half off topic, half still related, mostly curious, do you know how comes the volume get filled like that? I feels like I saw many similar problems during my researches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First **increase the volume size** from AWS (whether through UI/CLI/API)
- You will have to find anything **to delete from the root volume** to free up some space, since it is 100% full that it cannot execute basic command. (nothing big, +50/100M would do it, even less.)
- **run the growpart command** (which would increase the partition) --> your screenshots shows it was not executed properly, so you cannot resize your filesystem if the partition is not expanded, as nothing to resize. Normally, if it was successfully, run the lsblk again, you have to see nvme0n1p1 size increased.
- **Run the resize2fs command**.

Also, you have to use sudo when running this commands; that actually might have been **the reason for the permission denied error**.

Comment: Just before refreshing this page (so didn't see your answer yet) I desperately tried to temporary remove a picture from a data file, and indeed, that was the biggest issue. As of the sudo command, yeah, John mentioned it (I'm rather new to Linux, didn't know it would make a difference)
Just curious, as I asked via comment to my question, since I already saw similar issues, do you know how comes the storage can be filled to 100% like that despite not being used? (Yeah, it was running, but the instance is only used among friends, so nobody should be able to access it)

Comment: Many possible reasons; running applications writing logs to a file, dumping data to a temp file, a big file download ect..